# Операции со словарями и списками

Tags: java, arraylist, словари

Например, у меня есть два списка:

```
['a','b']
['1','2','3','4','5','6']
```

И у меня есть словарь:

```
Map<String, ArrayList> dict = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
```

Как мне записать в словарь элементы так, чтобы элемент первого списка был ключом, а три элемента второго списка были переменными этого ключа?
То есть должно получиться вот что:

`{a=['1','2','3'], b=['4','5','6']}`

Comment: Значение ключа всегда должно быть размером 3?

Comment: @RomanDanilov Да. Всегда 3.

Comment: А какого типа списки? Это коллекции ArrayList? Или массивы?

Comment: @RomanDanilov ArrayList

Comment: Почему строчки записаны в одинарных кавычках? В Java ведь строки записываются в двойных кавычках, а в одинарных сиволы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
List<String> firstList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
Map<String, List<String>> dict = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++) {
    List<String> values = secondList.subList(i*3, (i+1)*3);
    dict.put(firstList.get(i), values);
}
System.out.println(dict); //{a=[1, 2, 3], b=[4, 5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Или с guava (все равно она всегда есть в `CLASSPATH`)

```
List<String> keys = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b");
List<String> vals = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
List<List<String>> partitionedVals = Lists.partition(vals, 3);
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    map.put(keys.get(i), partitionedVals.get(i));
}

System.out.println(map);
```